# Need help understand search code in perl with \*{4}

Tags: regex, perl

Perl is one of my weaker languages. I am converting some older Perl code cleaning it up and removing dead code. In the code I have some search strings that read an input file for scientific computing which has mostly variables and numbers.

I have the string as an example

```
$tpl_file =~ s/\*{4}\s*(\S+)\s*\*{4}/$monte_inputs_array[$icase]{$1}/eg;
```

So I think , from what I have seen on line, the `\s*` is reading any number of white space  `/eg` evaluates replacement pattern and replaces in whole sting. The arrays `$monte_inputs_array[$icase]` is the array where I slurped in the code.

What I am not sure about is the `(\S+)` so that means any non-whitespace but not sure about the `+` 
Also I don't understand the `\*{4}` and in another string I have `\*{3}`.

Thanks

Comment: sorry above I meant /S means non white space not non number

Comment: `\*` - literal asterisk.  `{4}` four of them.  Four stars, any number of spaces, then at least one non-space, then any number of spaces, then four stars again.

Comment: @JulianFondren: that's an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\S+` means any quantity greater or equal to one of non-whitespace characters.

`\*{4}` means exactly four `*` characters.

You will find this documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), and [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).

Comment: `\S` does not have anything to do with numbers, except that numbers are in fact matched by it, because they are non-whitespace.

Comment: I see that the wording was unclear and lead to you misunderstanding the intent.  I meant any *quantity* greater or equal to one of non-whitespace characters, and have updated accordingly.

Comment: DavidO thanks for the answer and the document mentions I was having a hard time goggling it . I'll use those thanks

Answer (score 2):

`\S` matches any code code point that isn't whitespace.

`atom+` causes `atom` to be matched 1 or more times.

So,

`\S+` is a pattern that matches a sequence of non-whitespace at least one long.

---

`\*` is a pattern that matches `*`.

`atom{4}` causes `atom` to be matched 4 times.

So,

`\*{4}` is a pattern that matches `****`.

---

So,

`\*{4}\s*(\S+)\s*\*{4}` matches strings such as

```
****  FOO!  ****
```

but not

```
***  FOO BAR!  ***
```